# php mysql join three tables and sum item of same id

Tags: php, mysql

Everyone are in some level. I'm stock, I need help as I'm new to mysql.

Im trying to get the sum of materials(building) ordered to store and the sum of materials remove from store so I can get total materials remaining in the store, but I got duplicate result after joining the third table.

Here are my tables:

**Table: products**

```
serial name <br>

13  Windows<br><br>
14  Doors<br><br>
15  Ceramic Tiles<br><br>
16  Granite<br><br>
```

**Table: order_detail**

```
orderid productid quantity<br>

29  14  170<br><br>
30  15  2000<br><br>
32  15  200<br><br>
31  16  80<br><br>
17  1200    600<br><br>
```

**Table: matrequest**

```
id  matid   matname mquantity<br>
1   15  Ceramic Tiles   300<br><br>
2   15  Ceramic Tiles   300<br><br>
```

**Here is my code:**

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT a.productid, sum(a.quantity), b.serial, b.name, sum(mquantity) 
      FROM order_detail a 
      left join products b on a.productid = b.serial 
      left join matrequest c on b.serial = c.matid group by b.name")or die(mysql_error());

      while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
```

**RESULT :**

```
ID  Material Name   Order Quantity  Quantity Used   Quantity at Hand<br>
15  Ceramic Tiles   <b>4400 1200    3200</b>    <br><br>

14  Doors       170 0   170<br><br>

16  Granite     80  0   80<br><br>

17  Iron Rods   1200    0   1200<br><br>
```

**Suppose to be**

```
ID  Material Name   Order Quantity  Quantity Used   Quantity at Hand<br>
15  Ceramic Tiles   <b>2200 600 1600</b>    <br><br>

14  Doors       170 0   170<br><br>

16  Granite     80  0   80<br><br>

17  Iron Rods   1200    0   1200 <br><br>
```

Thanks in advance for assisting

Comment: help us first by making a sqlfiddle on http://sqlfiddle.com/ with table structure and example data, then you can and will get better help

Comment: @RaymondN ; I have not use the sqlfiddle before never know how to direct u to view the schema.

Comment: if you create a schema (create table and insert querys) and you push the button build schema your url in the browser should change, post that link here if you have made the schema

Comment: Ok. Thanks. here is it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13e21

Comment: Looks like you are joining onto 2 records in the `matrequest` table, which is doubling up the number of "Ceramic Tiles" records and hence your sums.

Comment: Do you have a reason for mixing storage engines because there all MyISM and matrequest is innodb? if you change matrequest drop the table and recreate don't alter the storage engine from innodb to MyISAM or the other way around, thats not good to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Second attempt after further comments:

```
SELECT
   a.productid,
   sum(a.quantity),
   b.serial,
   b.name,
   (SELECT SUM(mquantity) FROM matrequest c WHERE c.matid = b.serial)
FROM
   order_detail a 
LEFT JOIN
   products b 
      ON a.productid = b.serial 
GROUP BY
   b.name
```

See [updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c29920/1)

Comment: Thanks @Steve ID Material Name Order  Used At Hand 
15 Ceramic Tiles 4400 864 3536

Comment: Thanks @Steve When I added your code I got the expected result (Ceramic Tiles - 2200 600 1600 ) but when i added 132 to mquantity of matrequest table i got a new wrong result, ID Material Name Order  Used At-Hand  = 15 Ceramic Tiles 4400 864 3536, Order should be 732 not 864.

Comment: Don't hope your order_detail table will contain millions of records... that would really get the disk based temporary tables going if your server is misconfigured..

Comment: Further info; im trying to achieve a mini building material inventory system for real estate project. Material purchase into the store are stored on the "order_detail" table and material taken from the store are on the "matrequest". Hope that will help

Comment: @JamesO So are you saying you need to `SUM` the rows of matrequest sharing the same matid? In that case, would suggest using a subselect rather than JOINing on this table - see updated answer.

Comment: @SteveChambers Yes I appreciate your kindness. I have a feeling this will work, how do I present (SELECT SUM(mquantity) FROM matrequest c WHERE c.matid = b.serial) in php? I did this "$row['sum(MQUANTITY)']" and got error "Notice: Undefined index: sum(MQUANTITY)". "$row['sum(a.quantity)']" works gave a good result for orderfor

Comment: I updated your code (SELECT SUM(mquantity) FROM matrequest c WHERE c.matid = b.serial) to (SELECT SUM(mquantity) FROM matrequest c WHERE c.matid = b.serial) as total and present $row['total'] it works very well like magic. Thanks and God bless. Im going to add more data to see his well being